# Choosing locally basis of locally free modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose we are given a finite locally free module $M$ over an arbitray commutative ring $R$, i. e. we can find $f_1, ... f_n \in R$ generating the unit ideal s. t. $M[f_i^{-1}]$ is free of finite rank. Given a prime $p \in \text{Spec}R$ we can choose a basis $\{x_1, ... ,x_m\}$ of $M_p$, which is in the image of $M$ over $\kappa (p)$ which lifts to a minimal generating system of $M_p$ (thanks to Nakayama's Lemma), since $M_p$ is free, $\{x_1, ... ,x_m\}$  is a basis of $M_p$.

Can we deduce that, there exists a Zariski open ngbh $U$ of $p$ s. t. $\{x_1, ... ,x_m\}$ is basis of $\tilde{M}(U)$ or equivalently an element $f\in R\setminus p$ s. t. $M[f^{-1}]$ is free with basis $\{x_1, ... ,x_m\}$?

I think it is enough to finde a ngbh, where the $\{x_1, ... ,x_m\}$ generate $\tilde{M}(U)$, since after possibilly shrinking $U$, $\tilde{M}(U)$ is free of rank $m$, and so any generating system of $m$ elements is a basis.

Comment: Since $M$ is finitely generated, pick a set of generators, $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$. Write these as a linear combination of $x_i$ with coefficients coming from $R_P$. All these coefficients involve only finitely many denominators and so this is valid by just inverting one element . Can you finish it now ?

Comment: Ah yeah thanks. That step was missing to me, but now it is clear.